Inserting an image within a paragraph in textview
I am trying to insert a number of images, each within their own paragraphs respectively. Is there a way where i can do such a thing as in without breaking the string that contains the paragraphs ( a single string contains a number of paragraphs) or will i have to break down the string containing the paragraphs into a number of strings then add the images with spannable strings.
PS. I am a beginner and only knew about spannable strings from YT.
Thanks in advance
